# Making a jQuery sticky header, with multpile headers

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to imitate how gMail sticks the header to the top on scroll, when going past a certain part.

The code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.the-post').each(function() {
        var elem = $(this),
            y = $(window).scrollTop(),
            maxY = elem.children('.body').offset().top,
            header = elem.children('.header'),
            scrollHeight = 24;

        if(y >= maxY-scrollHeight) {
            $('.afloat').remove();
            header
                .clone()
                .appendTo('.post')
                .addClass('afloat');
            setSizes()
        } else $('.afloat').remove()
    })
})
```

I'm using .clone() because I don't want to interrupt the heighth of the page. When just adding the class, there's a slight nudge and it's exactly what I want to avoid.

However, it only does it on ONE of the posts. Can someone see why?

I also want to stop running the function once the header is there and the window is within boundaries.

**UPDATE**

So I figured this out. The problem with the above code was the else statement, it was removing the divs too fast. I improved it quite a bit and would love some more input, but this is working well and without overload:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(y >= maxY-24) {
        if(!isset) { 
            isset = true;
            $('.post').append(header
                .clone()
                .addClass('afloat')
            )
        } 
        $('.the-post').each(function() {
            var elem = $(this),
                maxY = elem.children('.body').offset().top,
                header = elem.children('.header');
            if(y >= maxY-24 && y <= maxY+24) {
                newtext = header.children('em').text();
                if(newtext != curtext) {
                    curtext = newtext;
                    $('.afloat').text(newtext)
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        isset = false;
        $('.afloat').remove()
    }
})
```

I had to re-do the logic here. I created the static header right away once applicable, so that I do not have to keep cloning divs.

Then I run through the divs (.the-post) with each, and made it a range-method so to prevent extra, useless queries.

Comment: check if it errors somewhere in the middle of code, usually thats the reason why the script is performed only to one element. I think it might be this line  header.clone()

Comment: I figured it out, it was removing the items too fast!

Comment: post your answer, so i can select it for points if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if(y >= maxY-24) {
    if(!isset) { 
        isset = true;
        $('.post').append(header
            .clone()
            .addClass('afloat')
        )
    } 
    $('.the-post').each(function() {
        var elem = $(this),
            maxY = elem.children('.body').offset().top,
            header = elem.children('.header');
        if(y >= maxY-24 && y <= maxY+24) {
            newtext = header.children('em').text();
            if(newtext != curtext) {
                curtext = newtext;
                $('.afloat').text(newtext)
            }
        }
    })

} else {
    isset = false;
    $('.afloat').remove()
}

})
```